# Smart Art Arrays

Tags: arrays, vba, powerpoint

I have written a for loop to check each font size used in smart art on a slide, and to output what the font size is for each block of text in the shapes. For some reason the first entry in the array updates correctly (e.g. I will have a block of text as a string concatenated with the font size) but any subsequent entries in the array only update the font size, but don't grab the actual block of text. The array is being counted properly (e.g. 5 smart art shapes is counted properly).

```
Dim j,e,f as integer
Dim osh as shape
Dim osl as slide

Dim smrtCount as integer
Dim osmrtSize()
dim osmrtSizeMatch()

set osl = activewindow.view.slide

For each
With osh in osl.shapes
If .Type = msoSmartArt Then
            smrtCount = smrtCount + .GroupItems.Count
            ReDim Preserve osmrtSizeMatch(1 To smrtCount)
            ReDim Preserve osmrtSize(1 To smrtCount)
            For j = 1 To .GroupItems.Count
                e = e + 1
                f = f + 1
                osmrtSize(e) = .GroupItems(j).TextFrame.TextRange.Runs(j).Font.Size 'store the sizes
                osmrtSizeMatch(f) = .GroupItems(j).TextFrame.TextRange.Runs(j).Text '& " = " & .GroupItems(j).TextFrame.TextRange.Runs(j).Font.Size '& vbCrLf
            Next j
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Need to use .smartart.allnodes() and not .groupitems:

```
osmrtSizeMatch(f) = .SmartArt.AllNodes(j).TextFrame2.TextRange.Text
```

Answer (score 0):

When addressing SmartArt via group items you need to do a .HasTextFrame check of the item otherwise it may error e.g when SmartArt includes a line.